# Generics 'T' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'typescript

Tags: typescript

working with simple generics argument example but ended up with two transpile time error

> Argument of type 'T' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never' for `this.data.push(item)`

> 'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be
> unrelated to 'undefined' for  `return this.data.shift()`

can anyone explain this error?

```
 class Queue<T>{
        data = [];
        push(item: T){ this.data.push(item); }
        pop(): T { return this.data.shift(); }
    }
    
    const queue = new Queue<number>();
    
    queue.push(123);
    queue.push(456);
    
    console.log(queue.pop().toPrecision(1));
    console.log(queue.pop().toPrecision(1));
```

Comment: `data = [];` -> `data: T[] = [];`

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/8944